# How to configure 2nd NIC to allow RDP in Windows Server 2016?

Tags: windows-server-2016, rdp

Windows Server 2016 running virtually in Hyper-V.  I have two NICs each with two different networks.  Primary NIC was being used for RDP.  I disabled the primary NIC and now I want to to RDP into the second NIC but RDP no longer works.  I don't know how to fix it.

Firewall settings are good to go.  Automatic metric is turned back on.  Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Does the second NIC have a valid IP address? Does it have a valid Default Gateway?

Comment: Yes, both NICs have valid IP addresses and valid gateways.  I apologize for not mentioning that - I was making an assumption.  port 3389 is broadcasting on all interfaces (0.0.0.0) as well.